# VBA - Fetch urls from excel file for IE to navigate

Tags: excel, vba

so far I have this code referring from an older one which fetches data from excel and puts it in SAP.

What I was hoping to do was for VBA to fetch the links in excel for IE to navigate in a single window after performing specific tasks.

```
Sub accounts()


Dim ie As Object
Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
'ShowWindow ie.hwnd, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED
ie.Visible = True


'Create objects to application, workbook and sheets
Set xclapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xclwbk = ActiveWorkbook
Set xclsht = xclwbk.Sheets("accounts")

'Line Reference
line_index = 2
link = ""


'Loop line
Label1:
    While Sheets("accounts").Cells(line_index, 1).Value <> ""

        'Get websites from Excel
        link = xclwbk.Sheets("accounts").Cells(line_index, 1).Value

        'Open link
        ie.Navigate link

            While ie.ReadyState <> 4 Or ie.Busy
               DoEvents
            Wend

        line_index = line_index + 1 'Loop

        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:3")) 'wait

    Wend

End Sub
```

It is now opening websites from excel but navigation fails after the 2nd line. Any thoughts?

I'm still trying to study VBA and any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: remove the quotes on trim?

Comment: Hey @NickSlash, thanks for the reply. However, IE navigates to  h t t p s://Trim(link) instead. :(

Comment: With ie and ie.visible = true should be outside of loop over cells containing urls; there is a missing End With, missing page wait lines and missing incrementing of line_index during loop; While loop also not complete in terms of syntax.

Comment: Is this actually VBA in excel? or is it VBS or something SAP related?

Comment: Hi @QHarr, I have edited the code and moved outside those you have mentioned. What is happening now is it's clicking the first link correctly, but when it goes to the second link, the program goes into error: Method 'Navigate' of object 'IWebBrowser2' failed

Comment: Are all the links valid in the cells that you are picking up and no blanks?

Comment: Yes @Qharr. For some reason, other websites work now, but fb links are stopping the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code as it stands in your post wont/shouldn't work. I don't think you're using VBA, possibly VBS within SAP? (that shouldn't be an issue) If your code example is a shortened version of your actual sub, it would be good to include the whole thing as your code as it might make understanding your problem easier.

Regardless, the browser opens and nothing happens.

In your line `.navigate "Trim(Link)"` not actually passing a trimmed version of link. You are passing the literal text "trim(link)"

The example below will navigate to URLs stored in range `Sheet1!A1:A10`
The code below the navigate command pauses the script while the page loads completely before continuing.

```
Sub Main()
Dim Browser As Object
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Dim Row As Integer
Dim Link As String

Set Browser = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Set Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Browser.Visible = True

For Index = 1 To 10
    Link = Sheet.Cells(Row, 1)
    Browser.Naviage Trim(Link)

    While Browser.ReadyState <> 4 Or Browser.Busy
        DoEvents
    Wend
Next Index

End Sub
```

**Update**

This is just a copy of your code above, adding the reference to internet controls wont fix your problem but having access to the intellitype data (code completion, method names etc) in the IDE can help with debuging.

The page(s) you are trying to click something on, are you able to give a link to see what you're trying to click?

When I run the below code it will navigate to all links on the sheet, ive added some lines to debug its process too.

If you'r in Excel, there is no need to create an excel object as its provided by default.

```
' Add Reference to "Microsoft Internet Controls" (Tools->References)

Sub AccountsTest()
Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
IE.Visible = True

Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Set Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("accounts")

Dim Row As Integer
Dim Link As String

Row = 2

Debug.Print "Starting Processing Links"

While Sheet.Cells(Row, 1).Value <> ""
    Link = Sheet.Cells(Row, 1).Value2 ' here

    Debug.Print "Navigating to <" & Link & ">"

    IE.Navigate Link

    While IE.ReadyState <> 4 Or IE.Busy
        DoEvents
    Wend

    Debug.Print "Navigation Complete"

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

    Row = Row + 1
Wend

Debug.Print "No More Links - End"

IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @Nickslash, I have updated the code and is now reading the data from the excel file. What is happening now is it's clicking the first link correctly, but when it goes to the second link, the program goes into error:

Method 'Navigate' of object 'IWebBrowser2' failed

I'm using VBA now, but the codes I'm using are heavily based from previous VBS from SAP. Thanks for your response. :)

Comment: It is now opening websites from excel but navigation fails after the 2nd row in excel. It just stops on that page and is not moving to the 3rd row. Though VBA seems to be still running as it is not showing any error, but not doing anything as well. Any thoughts?

Comment: Run-time error '-2147467259 (800040005)':

Automation error
Unspecified error

It still stops on the second link. :(

Right now I'm just trying to complete the navigation of the urls in the excel file. I also have added the reference to "Microsoft Internet Controls". This is really weird. I'm using MS office 365, IE 11, if this helps.

Comment: Try running it with some sample urls (google, so, bbc etc). Is link #2 similar to #1? can you share them?

Comment: Thanks again @NickSlash. Your code works when I use other websites (google, yahoo, etc.) I am trying to go to links of duplicate facebook profiles and for some reason, error shows up after the 2nd profile is loaded, and when I debug, it points to `While IE.ReadyState <> 4 Or IE.Busy`

Here are some samples:

- https://www.facebook.com/kara.lozano.7777
- https://www.facebook.com/henry.lozano.587
- https://www.facebook.com/henry.lozano.182
- https://www.facebook.com/henry.lozano.165033
- https://www.facebook.com/henry.lozano.547727

Comment: Strange, no issues for me on any of those links.

Comment: It is, I asked my colleagues to test it on their machine maybe it's an issue with my  PC. I'll update you once I get a response from them. Thanks again for your help @NickSlash!

Comment: Hey @NickSlash, I think I got it working now. The issue was I left out `IE.Quit` as I thought it could just keep a single IE window open and just reusing that window. Turns out closing and opening it was necessary for it to work properly. Thanks for all your help man, appreciate it.